# Can't navigate in the 3d view

Tags: interface

I started learning blender 2 days ago, but I'm still stuck in simple problem. I can't change the view using shift + right/left mouse button. The only thing I managed to do is zooming in/out. This's a screenshot from my window https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYqFm.png

[image]

Comment: I recommend taking a beginner's tutorial on navigation in Blender. I just looked at this one, and it covers the basics fairly well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHdTUJBs7so. Good luck, and have fun learning. :)

Comment: @DuaneDibbley It's not learning issue, I know how to navigate but it's not working for some reason

Comment: Then someone has given you some wrong info. I don't know what Shift+LMB is meant to do, because I've never tried using it, but Shift+RMB is used to select multiple objects in object mode or multiple vertices/edges/faces in edit mode.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley check the selected answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to enable "emulate 3 button mouse" in preferences?

[image]

windows could map your middle wheel/button to other functions (eg: double click), and it can break blender functions.

I had similar issues, and I started using a small utility called X-mouse, which can change mouse setting "per application"

[image]

And it changed my life... :D

Comment: finally somebody treated me like a not-noob ;) thanks, it works now.

Comment: @dotfreelancer I did not mean to be demeaning, and if that is how I came through to you, I apologise. This answer taught me something new as well.

Comment: no problem, I didn't mean that too..

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd> to click and pan the view.

<kbd>MMB</kbd> only to rotate the view around, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>MouseWheel Up / Down</kbd> to pan the view up and down and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>MouseWheel Up / Down</kbd> to pan left to right.

Comment: non of them working

Comment: @dotfreelancer if *really* none of them are working check that your mouse is working. These shortcuts are mapped to these actions  by default in Blender.

Comment: check the selected answer

Comment: Have you tried what the selected answer says? Also, are you using a touchpad or mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *User Preferences*

Select *Input* tab, then select *3D View*

[image]

Under *3D View (Globals)* change *Rotate View* to *MMB* where in the image shows *MMB*

[image]