# Navigation working in Object mode but not Edit mode?

Tags: interface

Hi I've got left mouse navigation working in object mode but in edit mode it doesn't work.

Alt Left - Rotate
Shift Alt Left - Pan
Ctrl Alt Left - Zoom

Also this only breaks when using left mouse selection

Any ideas why it would work in Object mode but not in edit mode?

Thanks,
Vaughan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this happens when you use "LEFT" click selection (not the default).

the shortcuts you used above need the "emulate 3 button mouse" setting enabled... which you can do with "RIGHT" click selection:

[image]

but as soon as yu enable "LEFT" click selection, the setting is unavailable (greyed), and thus those shortcuts doesn't work anymore

[image]

I guess you're on Windows, and I suggest you to use a little utility (called X-mouse, or a similar one) I suggested in another answer, here;

[Can't navigate in the 3d view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62672/cant-navigate-in-the-3d-view/62713#62713)

With that, you can have an automatic setup just for Blender mouse usage, and your 3 button mouse will use the middle button as it is intended by Blender, so you don't need the "emulate 3 button mouse" setting, and thus you don't need the shortcuts either...

hth

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, instead of using the select with left input preset you have to manually specify selection otherwise defaults override the alt left for navigation.