# Cant navigate/rotate in edit mode?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, customization, shortcut

I have the same issue as [Navigation working in Object mode but not Edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64922/navigation-working-in-object-mode-but-not-edit-mode) except I'm on Mac with external mouse.

Everything is great in object view, and I manually put in shift/left mouse for moving the view/rotating custom, but when entering edit mode these commands don't work anymore.

I tried changing to right selection and 3 emulate, but this results in nothing able to be moved/selected.

What can I do to have my rotate/move commands work the same in edit mode as object?

[image]