# Blender doesn't recognise Middle Mouse Button?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, 3d-mouse

so I got myself a new mouse (Logitech's M560), and I've found out that Blender kinda ignores its middle button (as in, rotation, panning and other functions that need this button don't work). But only with this mouse, and only in Blender.

- The mouse was originally set so that the middle button acted as an *app-switcher*, but I was able to set that to MMB in the SetPoint software.
- I tried the button in Firefox and couple of mouse testing programs and they all recognised it just fine. But Blender still doesn't read the middle button. The Left and Right buttons work properly.

  - Which is weird, because when I switch to an older and simpler 3-button mouse, there is no problem.

I'm thinking it's happening because Blender has some problem with Logitech's fancy Unifying drivers that apparently work differently than normal mouse drivers, or maybe the whole SetPoint business? (I don't know, that's only my speculation).

So I thought I'd ask here while waiting for a response from their support. I'll appreciate any advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: see this answer also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62672/cant-navigate-in-the-3d-view/

Comment: Note that this is not an issue with blender but with the hardware/driver and software for the mouse and how the OS is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the normal 2 click mouse you can pan and rotate.
Go to user preferences and follow the settings given in image below

[image]

To rotate the view, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the keyboard while pressing the <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> button and moving the mouse.

To pan, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys while pressing the <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> button and moving the mouse.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take this answer, even though I think I did just manage to find a different solution that I think suits me better. - I managed to use the software that came with the mouse and reassign the Middle button to one of the wheel tilt buttons, where it works for some reason. (Isn't it funny when the middle mouse button on a mouse doesn't work as a middle mouse button, but a completely different button does?)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same recently, my mouse used to 'rotate view' using the middle mouse button, but not now. I bought a new mouse, but this still had the same issue. Middle mouse button seems to work in other apps and registers with key press test apps.

When I reloaded factory settings, it configured the middle mouse button to 'rotate view' which now works fine!

I must have misconfigured the keymap configuration when trying to debug the issue with my old mouse (which I've since confirmed has a faulty middle mouse button).

Conclusion: a misconfigured keymap can also cause middle mouse button (or any button, depending on whats misconfigured) to appear broken.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by the having the industry compatible keymap active. In my case, I followed Blender Guru tutorial and forgot to switch back from the industry compatible keymap to the default one. The setting can be changed in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap* with the drop down at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered, but none of the answers solved my problem. I am also using a Logitech mouse, on Lubuntu.

I managed to solve the problem by installing [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/), (I'm sure other software will work but this one did the trick for me) and changing the Middle mouse button to `BTN_3`. Worked like a charm.

[image]