# Linux shortcuts keeps dominating the blender shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, linux, units

There are many shortcuts in Blender which are similar to that of Linux. For example if I have to select the lateral faces, I will do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. But in Linux <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> is also used to drag and move window across the screen. So therefore I cannot select the faces with shortcut in Blender and end up dragging the window. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can change the shortcut for Blender or change the shortcut on your Linux. I had the same problem with CTRL+R so I changed it to CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+R.

Comment: Check out the answers on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71567/blender-doesnt-recognise-middle-mouse-button/262478#262478) question. I had the same issue and managed to get it solved. But there are about 4 different solutions that might work.

Comment: You questions looks more like a Linux OS issue than Blender, if you are using an Ubuntu based OS, you could try Ubuntu Stack Exchange