# MMB Rotation not working

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I press the MMB to rotate around the 3D view it does not work, I can zoom in and out, just no pan rotation.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting all your settings (Blender)? Does the MMB press work in other applications?

Comment: could it be this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62672/cant-navigate-in-the-3d-view?

Comment: My mouse is partially broken, using the MMB softly it worked slightly.